# How to spell check all files of a given type using emacs

Tags: emacs, hunspell, aspell, ispell

Is it possible to spell check all files of a certain file type, e.g. all markdown files, in a directory and its subdirectories using Emacs?
I am looking for an interactive solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a status report or for an interactive fix-it-as-you-go method?